# Disassemble Memory

Tags: linux, 64-bit, intel, disassembly

I want to disassemble part of a program directly in memory. I am interested how generated code looks like when I investigate the stack and check how and where a certain routine was loaded and how it is bind and invoked.

Is there a ready to use program or library I can use to disassemble a certain byte sequence I extracted from a given location?

Comment: Yes, any debugger can do it. You just need to make sure the byte sequence starts at instruction boundary or the disassembler would return garbage.

Comment: What I am thinking of is a function I can call and it prints me lets say the next 100 op codes from a given memory address.

Comment: Debugger. If you want a function for compiled program, use some debugger library, eg. [LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org/).